# Navigation bar title font colour not being set using RGB but okay with standard colours

Tags: ios, objective-c

This works. It sets the font and the colour correctly:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  COA_TITLE_FONT(17.0),
  NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor brownColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
```

This makes the title go white - or at least that's what it looks like against a coloured background:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  COA_TITLE_FONT(17.0),
  NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor colorWithRed:62.0f green:116.0f blue:140.0f alpha:1.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
```

I use the RGB extensively in IB to set labels, buttons, etc., but can't set this one that way. I wonder if it is somehow getting a wrong tint colour, but the brown colour looks... well, brown.

Comment: all values should be divided by 255.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use decimal values for RGB. Divide all your floats by 255.0. Right now you're essentially setting it to pure white, as it just reads your >1 values as 1.0f

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  COA_TITLE_FONT(17.0),
   NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor colorWithRed:62.0f/255.0f green:116.0f/255.0f blue:140.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
```